# How to categorise a column in excel based on another column that contains value in string separated by semicolons

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following spreadsheet on the image (please click on link below for image):

[Raw data and categorised data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DxYZ.png)

Suppose I have the raw data Name B4:B11 and Interests C4:C11.

My question is I want to categorise the raw data so the output is as pictured in B16:B34 and C16:C34. I am trying to categorise people by their interests when their interests are in a column containing strings separated by semicolon. The Name can come up multiple times according to their interests where in this case Movie, Music and Radio.

Please kindly assist. Thanks kindly.

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This is what I tried: =IFERROR(
INDEX($B$4:$B$11,
SMALL(
IF($C$4:$C$11=$B$16, ROW($C$4:$C$11)- ROW($C$4)+1
),
ROWS($C$4:C5)
)
  ),"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This formula will work as in the picture below.**

This will need to be entered as an array formula (when in the formula bar hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$11,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B$15,$C$1:$C$11)),ROW($C$1:$C$11)-ROW(INDEX($C$1:$C$11,1,1))+1),ROW(1:1))),"")`

Array formula's break down ranges and calculate them them one cell (or row) at a time.

The SMALL formula (`=SMALL(array,k)`) will use the array results of the IF formula. The IF formula is returning either `FALSE` (default) or the row number when the text can be found in the cell using search, I have used `=ISNUMBER` to force true false rather than it throwing any errors as if it finds the text it will give a numeric value as the starting position of that string in that cell.

The `SMALL` formula puts the results in the array in ascending order and will only call on actual values (not `FALSE`) so I have used `ROW(1:1)` at the end of the small formula for the `k` part: When the row automatically increases to the next number, the next highest result is displayed.

I hope this helps explain the logic used.

[image]

Comment: Thanks kindly for your assistance. Your formula works great when I used only one word in the Interest category. When I tried using a combination of one word and two words in the Interest category for instance 1. Name: Tom | Interest: Action Movie; Rock Music; Jazz Music; Radio and 2. Name: Levie | Interest: Drama Movie; Music - and I do a categorisation on Music, my expected result should be Levie (only) but instead both Tom and Levie. How do I be specific when I select Music - only Levie shows up and when I do Action Movie only Tom shows up.

Comment: @Gogo Glad I answered your original question correctly. Please mark this as an accepted answer if it helped you to achieve your goal. Could I suggest to raise the new query as a separate question with a link to this one for background information. I only suggest this as re-working the formula to achieve what you want is going to be tough for me. I will give it a go but I might not achieve that and with a fresh question you will get seen by more users.

Comment: @Gogo I will also say that if you show some attempt with VBA I'd be happy to help steer you in the right direction as I can easily achieve it in VBA, though I just don't provide a free coding service

Comment: I posted a follow up question on the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573763/how-to-categorise-a-column-in-excel-based-on-another-column-containing-value-in please kindly assist.

Comment: @Gogo I will take a look at some point today but I have meetings all day so I might not get a chance until late afternoon